# Getting error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" while using map function in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks, slider

I've just started exploring React, I'm trying to add slider in my react project and that's not working I don't know why,So can someone guide me to find the issue and to fix it please.
And the code as follow appeared issue like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Here is the code :

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      
      this.IMAGE_PARTS = 4;
      
      this.changeTO = null;
      this.AUTOCHANGE_TIME = 4000;
      
      this.state = { activeSlide: -1, prevSlide: -1, sliderReady: false };
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.clearTimeout(this.changeTO);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
      this.runAutochangeTO();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ activeSlide: 0, sliderReady: true });
      }, 0);
    }
    
    runAutochangeTO() {
      this.changeTO = setTimeout(() => {
        this.changeSlides(1);
        this.runAutochangeTO();
      }, this.AUTOCHANGE_TIME);
    }
    
    changeSlides(change) {
      window.clearTimeout(this.changeTO);
      const { length } = this.props.slides;
      const prevSlide = this.state.activeSlide;
      let activeSlide = prevSlide + change;
      if (activeSlide < 0) activeSlide = length - 1;
      if (activeSlide >= length) activeSlide = 0;
      this.setState({ activeSlide, prevSlide });
    }
    
    render() {
      const { activeSlide, prevSlide, sliderReady } = this.state;
      return (
        <div className={classNames('slider', { 's--ready': sliderReady })}>
          <p className="slider__top-heading">Travelers</p>
          <div className="slider__slides">
            {this.props.slides.map((slide, index) => (
              <div
                className={classNames('slider__slide', { 's--active': activeSlide === index, 's--prev': prevSlide === index  })}
                key={slide.city}
                >
                <div className="slider__slide-content">
                  <h3 className="slider__slide-subheading">{slide.country || slide.city}</h3>
                  <h2 className="slider__slide-heading">
                    {slide.city.split('').map(l => <span>{l}</span>)}
                  </h2>
                  <p className="slider__slide-readmore">read more</p>
                </div>
                <div className="slider__slide-parts">
                  {[...Array(this.IMAGE_PARTS).fill()].map((x, i) => (
                    <div className="slider__slide-part" key={i}>
                      <div className="slider__slide-part-inner" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slide.img})` }} />
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="slider__control" onClick={() => this.changeSlides(-1)} />
          <div className="slider__control slider__control--right" onClick={() => this.changeSlides(1)} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  const slides = [
    {
      city: 'Paris',
      country: 'France',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/paris.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Singapore',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/singapore.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Prague',
      country: 'Czech Republic',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/prague.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Amsterdam',
      country: 'Netherlands',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/amsterdam.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Moscow',
      country: 'Russia',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/moscow.jpg',
    },
  ];
  

export default Slider
```

And I'm getting this error :

[image]

Guys how do I fix this issue? is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are passing the `slides` prop to your component?

Comment: Are You mean add it to App component?!

Comment: You should have `<Slider slides={slides} />` where you are using the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `slides` inside your class component so you don't need to get the slides from `props`.
You can access the slides without any medium. something like this:

```
{this.slides.map((slide, index) => (<TheSLiderElement/>)}
```

Comment: yeah that's working now thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your `slides` are defined globally not in the `props` but you try to access it through `this.props.slides` which does not exist. Either use it directly or add the slides in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.IMAGE_PARTS = 4;
  
  this.changeTO = null;
  this.AUTOCHANGE_TIME = 4000;
  this.slides = slides;
  this.state = { activeSlide: -1, prevSlide: -1, sliderReady: false };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities to this error.

```
this.props.slides // might be not an array, getting undefined or incorrrect value
```

First console this `this.props.slides` and check that if it meets the above criteria and data is in the correct structure and if yes then `add ?` check so that it listen to it asynchronously like this:

```
{this.props?.slides.map((slide, index) => ( //add the check here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your slides array is not a property. You have to set a slide array in your component state or you have to send this array in props. I use slides as an array in the state in this code block.

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      
      this.IMAGE_PARTS = 4;
      this.slides =slides;
      this.changeTO = null;
      this.AUTOCHANGE_TIME = 4000;
      
      this.state = { activeSlide: -1, prevSlide: -1, sliderReady: false };
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.clearTimeout(this.changeTO);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
      this.runAutochangeTO();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ activeSlide: 0, sliderReady: true });
      }, 0);
    }
    
    runAutochangeTO() {
      this.changeTO = setTimeout(() => {
        this.changeSlides(1);
        this.runAutochangeTO();
      }, this.AUTOCHANGE_TIME);
    }
    
    changeSlides(change) {
      window.clearTimeout(this.changeTO);
      const { length } = this.slides;
      const prevSlide = this.state.activeSlide;
      let activeSlide = prevSlide + change;
      if (activeSlide < 0) activeSlide = length - 1;
      if (activeSlide >= length) activeSlide = 0;
      this.setState({ activeSlide, prevSlide });
    }
    
    render() {
      const { activeSlide, prevSlide, sliderReady } = this.state;
      return (
        <div className={classNames('slider', { 's--ready': sliderReady })}>
          <p className="slider__top-heading">Travelers</p>
          <div className="slider__slides">
            {this.slides.map((slide, index) => (
              <div
                className={classNames('slider__slide', { 's--active': activeSlide === index, 's--prev': prevSlide === index  })}
                key={slide.city}
                >
                <div className="slider__slide-content">
                  <h3 className="slider__slide-subheading">{slide.country || slide.city}</h3>
                  <h2 className="slider__slide-heading">
                    {slide.city.split('').map(l => <span>{l}</span>)}
                  </h2>
                  <p className="slider__slide-readmore">read more</p>
                </div>
                <div className="slider__slide-parts">
                  {[...Array(this.IMAGE_PARTS).fill()].map((x, i) => (
                    <div className="slider__slide-part" key={i}>
                      <div className="slider__slide-part-inner" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slide.img})` }} />
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="slider__control" onClick={() => this.changeSlides(-1)} />
          <div className="slider__control slider__control--right" onClick={() => this.changeSlides(1)} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

    const slides = [
    {
      city: 'Paris',
      country: 'France',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/paris.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Singapore',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/singapore.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Prague',
      country: 'Czech Republic',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/prague.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Amsterdam',
      country: 'Netherlands',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/amsterdam.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Moscow',
      country: 'Russia',
      img: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/moscow.jpg',
    },
  ];
  

export default Slider
```

Comment: Yeah thank you for your answer thats work